# How do i make sure i get the correct Bellman Ford path?

Tags: algorithms, shortest-path

I was studying shortest path algorithms and was met with an issue regarding Bellman Ford for the image below.

[image]

Following the graph, i see that node 3 has a length of 1 while node 2 has a length of 2. When computing the path from 1 to 8 which is the correct path between 1->2->6->4->7->8 and 1->3->2->6->4->7->8 ?

I can see that 1->2->6->4->7->8 has the smallest path length but i'm confused because node 2 has length 2 while node 3 has length 1.

Will Bellman always give the shortest possible path or might it output a longer path because one of the nodes had shorter length but led to a longer path?

Comment: Nodes do not have lengths. *Edges* have lengths.

Comment: How about programming the algorithm and then running it and seeing what you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm):

> The Bellman–Ford algorithm is an algorithm that computes shortest paths from a single source vertex to all of the other vertices in a weighted digraph.

What is a shortest path? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem):

> In graph theory, the shortest path problem is the problem of finding a path between two vertices (or nodes) in a graph such that the sum of the weights of its constituent edges is minimized.

Wikipedia isn't always a reliable source, but in this case the definitions are spot on. Suppose that $G=(V,E,w)$ is a weighted undirected graph. A *path* between two vertices $x,y \in V$ is a list
$$ v_0 = x, v_1, \ldots, v_\ell = y $$
such that $(v_i,v_{i+1}) \in E$ for all $i < \ell$ (possibly $\ell = 0$). The *weight* of the path is
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\ell-1} w(v_i,v_{i+1}). $$
A *shortest path* between $x$ and $y$ is a path with minimum weight.

The Bellman–Ford algorithm finds the lengths of all shortest paths from a given vertex $x$ to all other vertices. It also generates auxiliary information which makes it possible to find the corresponding shortest paths.